# How to reload vimrc file on windows?

Tags: vim, reload

I am using `gvim` on windows. And while editing the `_vimrc` file I want to reload them immediately to see the change. How can I do it?

Comment: `autocmd BufWritePost ~/_vimrc source ~/_vimrc`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+reload+vimrc

Answer (score 0):

To refresh your _vimrc whilst you are editing it, just use

```
:so %
```

which is the shortened form of saying
"Source current file".

This will instantly apply your current vimrc but keep in mind that sourcing a new vimrc doesn't undo the effect of the old vimrc in your already open vim sessions.